# Does having a halo effect after LASIK disqualify you from being a pilot for the Air Force or commercial pilot?

Tags: pilots, medical

I had LASIK a while ago and I have some halo effects when I look at lights at night, and was wondering if that alone is something that would disqualify me from being a pilot for the Air Force or an airline?

Comment: Which country are you asking about?

Answer (score 4):

FAA doesn't allow airmen with complications like halos. etc. From [FAA Guide for Aviation Medical Examiners](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/guide.pdf):

> The FAA expects that airmen will not resume airman duties until their treating health care professional determines that their post-operative vision has stabilized, there are no significant adverse effects or complications (such as halos, rings, haze, impaired night vision and glare)...

A medical examiner should certify that the applicant (for pilot) is not suffering from any such complications:

> An applicant treated with a refractive procedure may be issued  a medical 
>   certificate by the Examiner if the applicant meets the visual acuity standards and the Report of Eye Evaluation (FAA Form 8500-7) indicates that healing is complete; visual acuity remains stable; and the applicant does not suffer sequela such as; glare intolerance, halos, rings, impaired night vision, or any other complications.

USAF doesn't allow individuals with cases where [the surgical outcome affects one's performance of duties](http://www.seymourjohnson.af.mil/Portals/105/Documents/MDG%20Docs/AFI%2048-123.pdf?ver=2016-02-17-110439-997); having a halo effect would be a disqualifier.